# WPF readonly DependencyProperty is editable in Properties window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I've created a WPF readonly DP like this

```
private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey IsFalsePropertyKey =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("IsFalse", typeof(bool), typeof(FlightDeckBoolExpressionConverter),
    new PropertyMetadata(false));

public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFalseProperty = IsFalsePropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

[Bindable(true), Browsable(true), Category("Common Properties"), Description("The result of the expression")]
public bool IsFalse {
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsFalseProperty); }
    private set { SetValue(IsFalsePropertyKey, value); }
}
```

My problem is that even though the property is readonly the user of the control can still set it in the editor as you can see in the image below (even though you get a compile time error)

[image]

This seems to happen only in the case of boolean properties. The input field of a `double` property for example, would not be editable.

I have also tried marking the property as readonly with the [attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.readonlyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) but that seems to have no effect.

Is there a way I can make the DP for this bool property readonly in the properties windows as well?

Comment: Two things: What happens if you remove the private setter entirely? I have seen two examples online and neither of them had a private setter, it was just a getter in both cases. The other one: Would it be possible to use a string representation in this case?

Comment: have you tried setting the "Browsable" flag to false so it does not show up in the editor for the user to even offer changing it?